# Laravel filter model relation

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a model with relations and I want to return only part of these relations that match a query.

But I don't achieve this,  every time every relations are return.

My models are

Lot

```
public function etageLots()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot');
 }
```

EtageLot

```
public function lot()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
}
public function fractions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Fraction','etage_lot_id');
 }
```

Fraction

```
public function etageLot()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot','etage_lot_id');
 }
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Type');
 }
```

And Type

```
public function fractions()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Fraction');
}
```

And here query that I tried :

```
$lots2 = Lot::whereHas('etageLots.fractions.type', function ($query)  { 
        $query->where('types.surface_ascenseur','>',0); 
    })
    ->with("etages.coeff")
    ->where('lots.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
dd($lots2->etageLots->first()->fractions);
```

(Return every fractions even if types.surface_ascenseur > 0)

```
$lots2 = Lot::with(['etageLots.fractions.type' => function ($query)  { 
        $query->where('types.surface_ascenseur','>',0); 
    }])
    ->with("etages.coeff")
    ->where('lots.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
dd($lots2->etageLots->first()->fractions)
```

(Return every fractions even if types.surface_ascenseur > 0)

```
$lots2 = Lot::with('etageLots.fractions.type',"etages.coeff")
    ->whereHas('etageLots.fractions.type', function ($q) {
        $q->where('surface_ascenseur','>',0);
      })
    ->where('lots.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
dd($lots2->etageLots->first()->fractions);
```

(Return every fractions even if types.surface_ascenseur > 0)

```
$lots2 = Lot::with(['etageLots.fractions' => function ($query)  { 
        $query->whereHas('type', function ($q) {
            $q->where('surface_ascenseur','>',0);
          });
        }
        ])
    ->with("etages.coeff")
    ->where('lots.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
dd($lots2->etageLots->first()->fractions)
```

(Return the right amount of fractions but without 'type' relation and I need it)

How to only return fractions with fractions.type.surface_ascenseur > 0 ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with the last one. Try:

```
Lot::with([
        'etageLots.fractions' => function ($query)  { 
            $query->whereHas('type', function ($q) {
                $q->where('surface_ascenseur','>',0);
            })
            ->with('type'); // <- add this!
        }
    ])
    ->with("etages.coeff")
    ->where('lots.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
```

Comment: Is it possible to sum a column from a nested relation with many array ?

Comment: I think it's possible. Depending on what you want.  To do it in the [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum), you can try something like: `$total = $lots2->sum(function ($lot) {
    return $lot->etageLots->fractions->type->sum('surface_ascenseur');
});`. But all the query builder aggregates are seemingly available besides [avg()](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#aggregates).